# Unset environment variable when Eclipse application is launched?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've got a situation where a user has the 'JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS' environment variable set on their workstation ... but the option is causing my Eclipse application to crash.

Is there a way, in the eclipse.ini file, that I can unset the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable?

Alternatively, is there a way I can just unset the -agentlib option on the JVM command line in the -vmargs section?

This is on a Windows system.

Comment: Can you not perform the unset operations in a batch script and start Eclipse from the same?

Comment: yes, but I would prefer not to have a batch script if possible ... right now the 'eclipse.exe' is launched directly and it's got an icon associated ... using a batch job would require extra setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you deploy your application as a product, have you tried to edit the **VM Arguments** section in the **Launching** tab of the **Product Configuration Editor**?

Comment: yes, but how do you change that setting on the VM args?  As far as I can tell, it's not a system property.  The value is picked up from the environment.